# Execute Android Java code with Javascript

Tags: java, android

I'm thinking of adding a local web server to my Android app so I can serve data from a local SqLite database through a web browser as long as the user's computer is on the same network at their phone.

Is it possible to write web code that "interacts" (for lack of a better word) with an Android `Activity`. For example, if I output a `List` of Java objects to HTML, can I add a button to the web page that will execute Java code to delete or insert from the Android SqlLite database?

Comment: Don't run a server on Android.  The OS is not meant for it.  In particular, it will aggressively kill any app that isn't in the foreground, leaving it only brief periods of time where it's allowed to run.  This makes it good for battery life, but unsuitable for a server because the server won't be reliable.

Comment: Well, it's for a media app so I already have a foreground service running.

Comment: Foreground services are only slightly more reliable.  It can still be killed at any time.

Answer (score 0):

While the web page itself can't directly execute Java code, you can establish communication between the web page and your Android code using a JavaScript interface in a `WebView` (so-called "bridge"). This allows you to call Java methods from JavaScript:

1. The bridge code:

   ```
   public class WebAppInterface {
       @JavascriptInterface
       public void performDatabaseOperation(String operation) {
           // Perform database operations in Java
       }
   }
   ```
2. In your Activity:

   ```
   WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
   webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
   ```
3. Call Java Method from HTML/JS:

   ```
   <button onclick="performDatabaseOperation('delete')">Delete from Database</button>

   <script>
       function performDatabaseOperation(operation) {
           Android.performDatabaseOperation(operation);
       }
   </script>
   ```

Comment: This won't work for the problem described in the question, which is to do this from a web browser (potentially on a different device, but it won't work from a browser on the same device, either).